# Clone a cloneable element of non-Cloneable object in pattern match

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I am working on a project which uses a `BTreeMap` with a custom `enum` for values. This `enum` cannot `#[derive(Clone)]`, because certain variants can include a value which is not `Clone`able. A rough outline of my project follows:

```
enum Foo {
    // Bar has impl Clone, Baz does not.
    // Both Bar and Baz are from external crates,
    // so I cannot impl Clone on Baz.
    A(Result<Vec<Bar>, Baz>),
    B(Bar, Qux),
    C,
}

struct Waldo {
    map: BTreeMap<Bar, Foo>,
    // Other variables...
}
```

Defining a method on my `Waldo`-analogue, I have encountered a situation where, inside of a recursive function, I am using `if let` to pattern-match on the result of `foo_map.get(&key)`; inside this `if` block, I am adding values to `map`. When later iterations of the recursive function see a value in `map`, they know they can ignore it. Something like this:

```
impl Waldo {
    fn do_something(&mut self, data: Bar) {
        // analyze puts a Foo into map with `data` as a key.
        // It can't return the value AND put it into the map, because
        // Foo would need to be cloneable. Instead...
        self.analyze(data);
        // I let `do_something_else` put the value in the map,
        // and then grab the value *from* the map.
        if let Some(&Foo::A(Ok(ref bar_vec))) = self.map.get(&data) {
            // bar_vec is cloneable, but even if I clone it,
            // `self.map` is still borrowed.

            // 'unique' is filtered so that it only contains
            // elements of bar_vec that aren't a key in `self.map`
            // 'unique' has no dependency on self.map,
            // because the iterator clones all elements
            // before collecting.
            let unique = bar_vec
                .iter() // &Bar
                .filter(|b| !self.map.contains_key(b)) // &Bar, sans those in map
                .cloned() // Bar
                .collect<Vec<Bar>>()

            // Give the newly encountered values a placeholder
            // so that recursions of the function will ignore them
            for new_item in unique.iter().cloned() {
                self.map.insert(new_item, Foo::C); // fails
            }
            // Once the items are inserted with placeholder values,
            // recurse the function to get their real values
            for new_item in unique.into_iter() {
                self.do_something(new_item);
            }
    }

    fn analyze(&mut self, data: Xyzzy) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to create a clone of `bar_vec` before I even leave the `if let` clause, which would mean that `self.map` is no longer borrowed. Is this possible, or will I have to refactor how my code works? I have already considered the option of making `analyze` return the `Foo` enum value rather than add it to the map directly, and have `do_something` match against the return value and add it to the map at the end, but I felt I may as well post the question and see if something less painful was possible.

Comment: What about Qux? Is that cloneable?

Comment: The easiest way would be fix that in the upstream repo, if possible :)

Comment: @hellow - Qux may or may not be cloneable, for the purposes of the example I didn't think it was relevant. The primary point is that the item extracted from `Foo::A` when the interior value is `Ok` *does* `impl Clone`, but `Foo` itself can't be `Clone`d.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your code contains a couple of errors which are not related to your question.

Comment: @red75prime Lack of sleep must have gotten to me. Tried to cut down my project as best I could. What are the errors in question?

Comment: `self.map.contains_key(&b)` expects `&Xyzzy`, but you pass `&&Bar`. Likewise `self.map.insert(new_item, Foo::C)` and `self.do_something(new_item)`

Comment: Borrows in the current stable version of Rust are scope-based, so you cannot "unborrow" `self` in `if let` scope. You need to mutate `self` outside of `if let` scope. Or use "non-lexical borrows" feature (`#![feature(nll)]`) of nightly compiler.

Comment: @red75prime - I *think* it should be logically sound now, assuming that `Bar` is cloneable but `Foo` isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use non-lexical lifetimes, if it is acceptable to you to use nightly compiler.

```
#![feature(nll)]

use std::collections::BTreeMap;

#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord)]
struct Bar;

// I cannot impl Clone on Baz
struct Baz;

enum Foo {
    A(Result<Vec<Bar>, Baz>),
    B(Bar),
    C,
}

struct Waldo {
    map: BTreeMap<Bar, Foo>,
    // Other variables...
}

impl Waldo {
    fn do_something(&mut self, data: Bar) {
        self.analyze(data.clone());
        if let Some(&Foo::A(Ok(ref bar_vec))) = self.map.get(&data) {
            let unique = bar_vec
                .iter()
                .filter(|b| !self.map.contains_key(b))
                .cloned() 
                .collect::<Vec<Bar>>();

            for new_item in unique.iter().cloned() {
                self.map.insert(new_item, Foo::C); 
            }
            for new_item in unique.into_iter() {
                self.do_something(new_item);
            }
        }
    }

    fn analyze(&mut self, data: Bar) {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

In the current stable Rust you have to mutate `self.map` outside of the `if let` scope as borrows are lexical and you can't "unborrow" a variable within the scope.

```
    fn do_something(&mut self, data: Bar) {
        self.analyze(data.clone());
        // This allows to access `unique` outside the scope
        // where `self.map` is borrowed
        let unique;
        if let Some(&Foo::A(Ok(ref bar_vec))) = self.map.get(&data) {
            unique = bar_vec
                .iter()
                .filter(|b| !self.map.contains_key(b)) // &Bar, sans those in map
                .cloned() 
                .collect::<Vec<Bar>>();
        } else {
            // early return prevents the use of uninitialized `unique`
            return;
        }
        for new_item in unique.iter().cloned() {
            self.map.insert(new_item, Foo::C); 
        }
        for new_item in unique.into_iter() {
            self.do_something(new_item);
        }
    }
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ac31f6f18b2cbc4cb15e9e4c8736822c&version=stable)

Comment: This is more or less the answer I expected, though I do have one question for the purposes of understanding: In the NLL example, would compilation fail if I did something else with `bar_vec` after the `for` loops (because that extends the requirement of the borrow)?

Comment: Yes, borrow lasts until the last use of borrower.